# Existence of collection of neighbourhoods of a point in a locally compact Hausdorff topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological space.

In '[Isomorphism with Small Bound](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-06/S0002-9939-1967-0217580-2/S0002-9939-1967-0217580-2.pdf)' by Cambern, page $1063,$ first sentence in the proof of Proposition $1,$ he quoted the followings:

> Let $x \in X$ be any point and **let $\{ U_i:i\in I \}$ be the family of neighbourhoods of $x,$** where the set of indices $I$ is directed by the usual manner of set inclusion ($i_1 \leq i_2$ if $U_{i_2} \subseteq U_{i_1}$.)
>
> **Question:** How to ensure that for every $x \in X,$ there exists the set
>   $\{ U_i:i\in I \}$?

If $X$ is first countable, then the set $\{U_i:i\in I\}$ exists by first countability. 
But, Cambern removed the first countability in the paper. 
So, how to guarantee the existence of $\{U_i:i\in I\}$?

Comment: The space $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact, right? So every point $x\in X$ has a local base of relatively compact neighborhoods.

Comment: Is he considering the net of open sets over some not linear index?

Comment: @WilliamElliot the neighbourhoods *are* the indexing set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(I, \le)$ is a directed set, as in the definition of a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). It is sort of a tautology here as neighbourhoods in reverse inclusion order, are the "canonical" example of a directed set defined from a topological space. Note that $I$ does not have a linear order, just a partial order, with the property that for any $i_1, i_2 \in I$ we have some $i_3 \in I$ with $i_1 \le i_3, i_2 \le i_3$ (which for neighbourhoods is just their intersection).

I think the $I$ is just introduced as a notational "sugar". In fact, the index set "is" the set of neighbourhoods of $x$ itself (or bijectively mapped with it), and the order is (or corresponds to) reverse inclusion. The $i$'s are easier to use in formulae, e.g. Also, in the proof of that proposition the author defines another net with that same index set.

Comment: Actually I just want to know that given a point in a topological space, can we always have a neighbourhood of the point.

Comment: @Idonknow There is always the system of neighbourhoods: $\mathcal{N}_x = \{A \subseteq X: \exists O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O \subseteq A\}$ So all open subsets that contain $x$ and their supersets are the neighbourhoods by definition. In a locally compact Hausdorff space, any neighbourhood contains a compact one.